# How to test a function inside React functional component using jest.spyOn with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is a simple React component. I'm using React Testing Library for unit testing components and I was not able to test the `handleClick` function of `TestComponent` using `jest.spyOn()`. Could anyone please help?

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = (props) => (
  <button onClick={props.handleClick}> {props.text}</button>
);

const TestComponent = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('clicked!');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button text="Test Button" handleClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

**Test**

```
  it('expect spy to be called', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<TestComponent />);
    
    const spy = jest.spyOn(TestComponent, 'handleClick');
    
    const button = getByText('Test Button');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The error that I'm getting is below. I tried using `TestComponent.prototype` in `jest.spyOn` but that does not help either.

```
Cannot spy the handleClick property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

Comment: In short, you'll want to test the **result** of calling `handleClick`, not necessarily that it was invoked. For example, when clicking on the button, it should cause something to happen to the DOM/URL (an alert is shown, a counter is updated, some text was sent to an API, the URL was changed, and so on). Again, test the against the result, not the action. On a separate note, you can't spy on a function expression within a functional component because it's not a property of the function (in short, `TestComponent.handleClick` is not a function).

Comment: If you want to learn more about prototypal inheritance (which **isn't necessary** for creating/testing React functional components), then read this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#inheritance_with_the_prototype_chain). Almost forgot: Since you're not necessarily updating the DOM/URL, your test should focus on asserting that `console.log` was called with "clicked" when the button is clicked... which requires mocking `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't spy `handleClick` event handler since it's defined in functional scope, it's **private**.

Your best test component behavior rather than implementation, such as what method is called inside the event handler, you should not go to mock and assert whether these methods are called, but what changes have occurred, such as what happens to the component, UI, DOM tree, etc.

But in your example, the `handleClick` event handler does not do anything, just calls `console.log`, then you can only assert whether the `console.log` is called indirectly assert whether the `handleclick` is called.

```js
// arrange
const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log')
// act
// ...
// assert
expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```